# Fetch still throws despite having catch block

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

```
fetch('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/aassdd')
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.status);
  })
  .catch((e) => { console.log('ha'); });
```

For some odd reason the code above will still throw error and execute the `.then` statement afterwards. Is there a way to fix this ?

Edit: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f91fL3ss/)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be throwing. Are you perhaps just seeing the 404 request error being logged to the console?

Comment: A `404 Not Found` isn't really an error that would be caught.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara in jsfiddle if you open the console, does it not show a get Error for you ?

Comment: @adeneo is there any way to go around it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browser developer consoles normally logs 404 errors by default, and some may, or can be configured to, log all requests.

[image: Console screenshot]

The fact that you see see an error here doesn't mean a catch-able JavaScript exception was thrown, in addition to JavaScript console logs and throw exceptions, the browser console also shows other things.

There isn't anything you can do in your code to stop this error from appearing in the console, but some consoles would let you hide those requests from the console.

Also, `fetch` does not throw an error on typical error response codes like 404. This is to make it more-flexible, and let you decide if you still want the content, even if it is a 404 response code.

If you want to throw an error on a non-200 status code, you could do this:

```
fetch('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/aassdd')
  .then((resp) => {
    if (resp.status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('Invalid status code: ' + resp.status);
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => { console.log('ha'); });
```